# onclick needs 3 clicks to complete event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this question has been asked more than once, but the answers I have found don't seem to apply to my situation... I am very novice at JavaScript, and even more so at debugging it.  I am trying to lean by working through an online tutorial, but when I tried the onclick event, everything appears to be null at first - the function is supposed to resize the canvas and place the image in the top left corner on the first click.  What is does is resizes the canvas on the first click, then on the 3rd click, adds the image...  Since I am not calling on the style or display (to my knowledge), and there are no conditional statements in the function, I'm not sure why this is happening.  I also tried to link the function instead of inline as suggested by another post, but to no avail... I am using Chrome.   Any input would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" onclick="changeCanvasSize(this);" width = "400" height = "300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
function changeCanvasSize()
{
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var avatarImage = new Image();

    gameCanvas.width = 600;
    gameCanvas.height = 800;

    avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png";
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, 0, 0);
}
```

css:

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;  
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 20px; 
    color: #575757; 
    font: 14px/21px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #B93F14;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ol {
    width: 600px; 
    text-align: left; 
    margin: 15px auto
}

canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Could you share us what tutorial you are following? I am curious of why the re-size of the canvas would occur when you click within the canvas instead of a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to wait for the image to load before inserting it:

```
function changeCanvasSize()
{
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var avatarImage = new Image();

    gameCanvas.width = 600;
    gameCanvas.height = 800;

    avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png";
    avatarImage.onload = function() {
        gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Macmee!  This is something that was not even addressed in the tutorial.  This is the answer.